# How to solve one kind of integral problem analytically

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I have to solve a kind of integral problem analytically :
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-x}}P_n(x)\text{d}x
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is Legendre polynomial, $i$ is imaginary unit and $k$ is a constant. Given $n$, Mathematica can help me get the very answer.

But I want to make sure whether there are some other methods that can help get the general answer, i.e., not given $n$ before. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,P_n(x)\,dx &=& 2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-ik\sqrt{2}x} P_n(1-2x^2)\,dx\\&=&\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{2x}}}{\sqrt{x}}P_n(1-2x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence we are essentially decomposing $\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{2x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$ in terms of the [shifted Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials).

In order to compute the last integral, we can expand $\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{2x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$ as a Taylor series, then exploit:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}P_n(2x-1)\,dx &=& \frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-x)^n\,dx=\frac{\alpha!^2}{(\alpha+n+1)!(\alpha-n)!} \end{eqnarray*}$$
that follows from integration by parts.